# org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, server

What am I missing ? I already tried a lot of thing to fix that but I'm still getting the following error:
What cand I do to solve this problem?

```
May 14, 2016 10:13:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/visminer-dashboard]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/visminer-dashboard]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [org.visminer.servlets.MetricsServlet] and [org.visminer.servlets.RepositoryServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/RepositoryServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2055)
```

Comment: I put bellow the web.xml.

Comment: The error says you have 2 servlets mapping to /RepositoryServlet. If they are not registered in web.xml I'd say they are annotated with @WebServlet?

Comment: I see, hum but they are with the @WebServlet notation. Besides that  tried to make a fresh web project with just an html page into that. However, I'm getting this error:                                                                                                                         



org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: So, I don't know what's happening.

Comment: I don't know about the second error either. But it seems you have MetricsServlet and RepositoryServlet both mapped to the same urlpattern in @WebServlet annotation. You must change 1 of them - thats what the error says

Comment: Actually I mapped the Metrics Servlet missing the letter 's'. Lol, Thanks a lot @JaqenH'ghar

Answer (score 0):

@Jaqen H'ghar

The web.xml if needed, but I do not know if that xml is the correct or if he one from the tomcat is the right one.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>visminer-dashboard</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Visminer Loader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.visminer.servlets.RepositoryMinerLoader</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.visminer.filter.UrlFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```